# Auto Saving File to Text Without Quote

Tags: excel, vba, save

I save a file to Text Format. Upon opening, it seems have quotes on the file.
It show like this " 16,347.21 ". I'm in German format. It should be 16,347.21.
How can I remove it?

```
Dim path As String
Dim filename As String
path = Range("FolderPath").Text
filename = Range("FileName").Text
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=path & "\" & filename & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlText
ActiveWindow.Close
MsgBox "Data for Upload Saved"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 1):

**xlTextPrinter** doesn't seem to include quotes on real numbers. Try:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=path & "\" & filename & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter
```

[image]